# Drawing random subspaces from Grassmannian with uniform probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, grassmannian, haar-measure

Consider the Grassmannian manifold $G(M, N)$ of $M$-dimensional subspaces in $R^N$. I want to approximate (stochastically) an integral of the form
$$
\int_{G(M, N)} f(v) \, dv,
$$
where $f : G(M, N) \to R$ is some function and $dv$ is the Haar measure on the Grassmannian. I want to approximate the integral with sampling, and therefore I need a method to uniformly draw samples with respect to the measure dv.

I'm happy about hints / references on how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by Haar measure here?

Comment: It's the pushforward measure of the Haar measure on the orthogonal group $O(N)$ under the map $f_H(g) = g H, g \in O(N)$, $f_H : O(N) \to G(N, M)$. I found this paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609050 which provides a method to uniformly sample from $O(N)$ which by the above solves my question I think.

Comment: Fill an $M\times N$ matrix with independent standard Gaussian random variables.  The row space will have the desired Haar distribution.

Comment: @kimchilover Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Călin A standard reference is A. T. James, "Normal multivariate analysis and the orthogonal group". _Ann. Math. Statistics_ 25 (1954), 40–75.  But there might be newer & more accessible explanations.  If I find a good one I'll post it here.

Comment: @kimchilover I think I understood why that works (see my answer), but in the meantime I came to wonder the following: is the Haar measure on the Grassmann manifold the same as the measure induced by its Riemannian structure coming from its quotient geometry? See, e.g., [Edelman et. al](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0895479895290954).

Answer (score 2):

To expand on one of the comments to your question. Indeed, sampling each component of an $M \times N$ matrix independently from the standard normal distribution yields a random $M$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Using the same reference as in [this (related) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3097862/261538), i.e., [Chikuse, Y. (2003). Statistics on Special Manifolds](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387001609), we have from Theorem 2.2.2. that if the elements of $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ are i.i.d. from $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, then $P = Z (Z^\top Z)^{-1} Z^\top$ is uniformly distributed on the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ containing rank-$M$ projection matrices $P = X X^\top$, which is just another representation of the Grassmann manifold.

Thus, if you instead represent points via the column space of rank-$M$ matrices from $\mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$, you can use the matrix $Z$ directly. Note that $Z^\top Z$ has almost surely full rank, so its inverse above only amounts to a change of basis which should keep you in the same equivalence class (i.e., same Grassmann point).

Similarly, if you use orthonormal $M$-frames, then Gram-Schmidt should give you yet another representation of the same subspace.